# SQL : get one particular book owner

Tags: sql

I have a `Student` table with columns like this:

```
| email (PK) | name |
```

I have a book table with columns as such:

```
| bookid(PK) | title |
```

I have a **copy** table which have copies of books people own

```
| emailofOwner(FK to student.email) | bookid(FK to book.bookid) |
```

A student can of course own multiple books. My aim is to find names of students who own only 1 such book and nothing else BUT with a bookid = 3;

My attempt to get people who own only 1 book.

```
select c.emailofOwner
from copy c
group by c.emailofOwner
having count(*) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Can you clarify "nothing else with a bookid=3" ?

Comment: means the student should not own book 3 and book 4. only book 3

Comment: So you mean students that own book 3 and ONLY book 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM student t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emailofOwner
    FROM copy
    GROUP BY emailofOwner
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bookid) = 1 AND MAX(bookid) = 3
) t2
    ON t1.email = t2.emailofOwner
```

The above query uses a subquery to restrict to students who own one and only one book whose ID is `3`.  The subquery is identical to your attempt except that it adds the restriction that the max book ID is `3`.  In this case, since there will only be one book per retained group, this is simply checking the value of the book ID.

Comment: What if the book ID is `2`?

Comment: @Owen Then it would fail, clearly since the max book ID would be 2, not 3.

Comment: @FelyppOliveira You might be right about using `DISTINCT` if the OP be concerned about duplicates, but I think just using `MAX` (or `MIN`) should suffice because each group would then still have the same book, albeit perhaps many copies.

Answer (score 1):

To get students with only

```
select s.name, s.email, count(*) as numBooks
from student s, copy c
where s.email = c.emailOfOwner
group by email
having count(*) = 1
```

And people with book 3 and ONLY book 3:

```
select s.name, s.email, count(*) as numBooks
from student s, copy c
where s.email = c.emailOfOwner
group by email
having count(*) = 1 and min(bookId) = 3;
```

Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4b4c1/3).